# Database Change Notification not coming to jdbc driver client after sometime

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I register a Database Change Notification in oracle 12c. 
I get the notification whenever new record is inserted in the table. But after sometime say 7 hrs, the notification stop coming to the client.

Java client is running without any error but not sure what goes wrong after approx 7 hours.
Below is the code-

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty(oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS, "true");

p.setProperty(oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection.NTF_TIMEOUT, "0");
dcr = oracleConnection.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(p);
dcr.addListener(listener);
statement = oracleConnection.createStatement();
((OracleStatement)statement).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);
rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next())
{  }
```

Please suggest what could be the issue.

Comment: Have you tried with the NTF_QOS_RELIABLE property? The value can be set to "true".

Comment: Tried with NTF_QOS_RELIABLE property as true. Still the issue persist.
Below is the test result-
Records are inserted at -
 08/Jan/2018 01:46:15
08/Jan/2018 02:46:15
08/Jan/2018 05:46:15
08/Jan/2018 10:46:15
08/Jan/2018 17:46:15
09/Jan/2018 02:46:15

Notifications received -
08/Jan/2018 01:46:15  -rowId :: AAdSn3AC2AAAlL8AAA
08/Jan/2018 02:46:15  -rowId :: AAdSn3AC2AAAlL8AAB
08/Jan/2018 05:46:15  -rowId :: AAdSn3AC2AAAlL8AAC
08/Jan/2018 17:46:16  -rowId :: AAdSn3AC2AAAlL8AAE

The notification missed was at 10:46:15 and then received the notification for 17:46.